# ligature with special characters: fī

Tags: bibtex, compiling, accents, ligatures

I am using a lot of special characters such as ā, ī, ū, š, ṣ, ḥ, ḫ and so on. I just spotted that sometimes this causes problems with ligatures for example the fi-ligature, if the dot on the i is a dash: fī.

In my MWE below I am using the Brill font: http://www.brill.com/author-gateway/brill-fonts .

I've come so far to have learned that there are three options to set `fī`:

If you want to get an MWE, please download it from here: http://www.arabic-philosophy.com/misc/minimal_fi.tex (Copy&Paste into this forum did not work because it made Option 1 and 3 be identical in sight.)

This is the result: http://www.arabic-philosophy.com/misc/minimal_fi.pdf

Option 1 is the one that emerges when I type a `f` and an `ī`.

Option 2 has been suggested by tohecz.

Option 3 is the one I'd prefer.

Is there a way to enable myself just to type as I used to but to tell LuaLatex to use option 3 instead of 1 as the output? What in fact is the difference between 1 and 3?

Comment: Are you sure there is an fī ligature to begin with? What about showing a MWE?

Comment: no, you're right. there is in fact none but I thought maybe it just makes a normal fi-ligature and then adds a dash. Anyway, as you see above, sometimes there is unnecessary space between f and ī and sometimes it is not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your option 3 is using

> U+0069 (LATIN SMALL LETTER I) U+0304 (COMBINING MACRON)

instead of

> U+012B (LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH MACRON)

You get the former when inputting the latter by using

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ī}{ī} % use "i + combining macron" in the second argument
```

or, without too much hassle in inputting strange characters,

```
\newunicodechar{ī}{i\char\string"0304 }
```

This is the output from your test file (omitting option 2).

[image]

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Brill}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ī}{i\char\string"0304 }

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
1a. Kitāb an-Naǧāt fī l-ḥikma.

1b. \emph{Kitāb an-Naǧāt fī l-ḥikma}.

3a. Kitāb an-Naǧāt fī l-ḥikma.

3b. \emph{Kitāb an-Naǧāt fī l-ḥikma}.
\end{verbatim}

1a. Kitāb an-Naǧāt fī l-ḥikma.

1b. \emph{Kitāb an-Naǧāt fī l-ḥikma}.

3a. Kitāb an-Naǧāt fī l-ḥikma.

3b. \emph{Kitāb an-Naǧāt fī l-ḥikma}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: wow. this works very fine. There's one follow up problem to this, though: the headings in the headlines now misprint the dash on the i: the dash is no longer on top of the i but a little more than one character before the i. any ideas?

Comment: @ClintEastwood No example, no idea. :)

Comment: ok... =) I changed the MWE (tex and pdf) accordingly.

Comment: Strange: if I compile with XeLaTeX I get the expected result, but not with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I have been having this error for weeks, but paid no attention to it as I ascribed it to the over-all and initial problem of how to write this fī-ligature (or no-ligature). now, however, it appears to be rather noteworthy.

Comment: The so-called "problem" magically vanished. Everything's fine now.

Comment: Have here `\usepackage{fontspec}` and those declarations will work. It would be nice to get a complete minimal code here.

Comment: @Masi I added the code

Answer (score 11):

In my humble opinion, `fi` shouldn't be ligatured when `i` has some other top-accent than a dot. You can do that by putting the empty braces `{}` between the letters: `f{}ī`. This image shows some variants, the last one is `fi` overlapped with `\=\i`, for comparison (I show the code as well, utf8 char `ī` doesn't work for me hence the `\=` command):

[image]

Comment: interesting. When I use `f{}ī`, then what I have called "error" occurs. (See the picture I just added to my question). Maybe this then is an error of the Brill font?

Comment: The empty braces `{}` supresses both **ligatures** and **kerning of pairs**, i.e. the characters will have their boxes just next to each other. That's why the `ī` letter might get moved right. But still, there should be correct placement of `.` after `ī`.

Comment: is there a way to "force" ligatures or to do the exact opposite than `{}` so that the boxes are not simply put next to each other?