# How to have this Latvian letter "i" with top bar in LaTeX?

Tags: letters, latvian

I am trying to type the `i` with the top bar in Fig. 1. 
I did not find any corresponding symbol in the glossary [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters). 
[Detexifying](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) it also gives bad results. 
I would like to get it without `fontspec`. Pseudocode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
% TODO here the letter i with top bar
\end{document}
```

Failed attempt with `\={i}` giving output in Fig. 2.

Fig. 1 Expected output for Latvian `i` with the bar at the top, 
Fig. 2 Failed output

[image]
[image]

Expected letter in Wysiwyg: `ī`

Comment: In your code your are using `fontenc`. However using `fontspec` means you are compiling with `lualatex` or `xelatex`. In this case you can simple type your letter. It's the same like here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230281/how-to-have-this-latvian-letter-s-with-top-nose

Comment: Sorry *with* and *without* is too similar ;-)

Comment: This 'works for me' with `ī` as the input and an up-to-date TeX system, which gives the same result as `\=\i`. Can you post the `.log` you get?

Comment: @JosephWright Confirmed works also in my updated system now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using inputenc in your example you can (since the 2015 latex release) just type ī directly (or use the traditional `\=\i`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
ī
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do the following with ligature (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48518/13173)

```
\={\i}
```

Output

[image]